# Using linux source command in Dockerfile gives error

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, sh

I download and install `Go` programming language like this:

```
curl -OL https://golang.org/dl/go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xvf go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
touch /etc/profile.d/go.sh
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> /etc/profile.d/go.sh
source /etc/profile.d/go.sh
```

And it works. But I want to create a `Docker` image containing Go and ready to use. So I did like this in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN curl -OL https://golang.org/dl/go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local -xvf go1.17.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN touch /etc/profile.d/go.sh
RUN echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" >> /etc/profile.d/go.sh
RUN source /etc/profile.d/go.sh
```

But it gives me error:

```
 > [25/25] RUN source /etc/profile.d/go.sh:
#28 0.737 /bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

How I have to do this? Im using `ubuntu 20.04` as a base Docker image

Comment: `source` is only in bash, not sh; the comparable sh command is `.` (as in, `. somefile` instead of `source somefile`).

Comment: Also, `RUN source /etc/profile.d/go.sh` doesn't actually do anything useful. Each RUN happens in a new shell, so changes you make to variables in a previous RUN don't change which variables are set in the next one.

Comment: (BTW, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/dot.html is the POSIX specification for the `.` command).

Comment: ...if you want to permanently change the PATH (or any other environment variable) for all future `RUN`s in a Dockerfile, that's what the `ENV` statement is for. No need to muck with the shell profile at all.

Comment: There are official `go` docker images which do not require you to install go